# How can I correctly illustrate the impact of a Fractional Fourier Transform on a signal's Wigner-Ville Distribution?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, time-frequency

A linear frequency modulated chirp signal produces a Spectrogram and Wigner-Ville Distribution that look like this:

[image: Spectrogram and WVD of LFM chirp]

My understanding of the fractional Fourier transform is that it corresponds to a rotation in the time-frequency plane - from [Wiki](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fractional_Fourier_transform):

> [FT goes time to freq. IFT goes freq to time.] Fractional Fourier transforms transform a signal (either in the time domain or frequency domain) into the domain between time and frequency: it is a rotation in the time–frequency domain.

with examples for different angles:

[image]

I'm using the fractional Fourier transform implementation called `frft2.m` found [here](https://nalag.cs.kuleuven.be/research/software/FRFT/). You set the angle of rotation by defining the parameter `a` where `theta = a*pi/2` (theta is the desired rotation angle). If `a` is one, the frft becomes the fft.

In order to verify all this, I try computing the fft, the frft with `a = 1`, and the frft with `a = 0.5` (i.e. a rotation of 45 degrees). I ran the following code in Matlab and the results are plotted below:

```
%% Chirped waveform
clearvars
close all

fs = 1e3;
t = 0:1/fs:0.5;
L = length(t);
y = chirp(t,0,0.5,500);

[d,f,t] = wvd(y,fs);

%% Fractional Fourier Transform
fft_y = fftshift(fft(y));
fr_y = frft2(y,1);
fr2_y = frft2(y,0.5);

[d2,f2,t2] = wvd(fr2_y,fs);
```

[image: Distributions]

There are several behaviors here that I haven't been able to understand:

The top left uses Matlab's `fft` function while the top right uses what should be the equivalent frft2 with `a=1`. I assume I am not shifting/rearranging the frequencies correctly with fft which is why the two are flipped copies of one another. However, why does the frft or fft produce a mirrored copy of the signal along the time axis?
Additionally, I assume this mirroring is partly responsible for the strange behavior of the frft in the bottom left spectrogram where I'm trying to rotate by 45 degrees. How can I correctly account for this when performing the frft so I don't have random overlapping frequency bands all over the place? The wvd in the bottom right is the wvd of the same signal where the 45 degree frft has been applied.

**Update:**

Based on @GrapefruitIsAwesome's comment, I tried starting with a complex linear chirp:

`y = chirp(t,0,0.5,500,'complex');`

[image: Complex Linear chirp]

And the corresponding ffts, frfts and WVDs:

[image: Distributions2]

Seems somewhat better with less unintentional mirroring but I feel like I'm still missing what's going on with the underlying mechanism here. For reference, what I'm hoping to replicate is something along the lines of what we see in the example given in the applications section of [this wiki page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fractional_Fourier_transform#Application).

**Update 2**

Per request in the comment, this is the code I used to generate the plots. It appears I didn't realize the comments were referring to `spectrogram` and not `pspectrum(__,'spectrogram')` in matlab. I believe `spectrogram` can be made to match the output of `pspectrum`, however, I prefer pspectrum since it handles much of the windowing and other details for you.

```
figure
tiledlayout(1,2)

nexttile
pspectrum(y,fs,'spectrogram','TimeResolution',0.1, 'OverlapPercent',99,'Leakage',0.85)
title('LFM Chirp Spectrogram')

nexttile
imagesc(t,f,d)
axis xy
colorbar
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Frequency')
title('LFM Chirp WVD')


figure
tiledlayout(2,2)

nexttile
pspectrum(fft_y,fs,'spectrogram','TimeResolution',0.1, 'OverlapPercent',99,'Leakage',0.85)
title('Matlab fft spectrogram')

nexttile
pspectrum(fr_y,fs,'spectrogram','TimeResolution',0.1, 'OverlapPercent',99,'Leakage',0.85)
title('frft2 spectrogram')

nexttile
pspectrum(fr2_y,fs,'spectrogram','TimeResolution',0.1, 'OverlapPercent',99,'Leakage',0.85)
title('frft2 45 degree spectrogram')

nexttile
imagesc(t2,f2,d2)
axis xy
colorbar
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Frequency')
title('frft2 45 degree WVD')
```

Comment: How are you producing the spectrogram. When I use `spectrogram(y)` in matlab, I do not get the mirrored version you have. I do, however, get something like that when I take `spectrogram(fr_y)`.

Comment: I believe chirp() generates a real signal. Gave you tried a complex chirp?

Comment: @PeterK. That is what I posted above. `spectrogram(y)` also produces the very first plot which doesn't have a mirrored component since y is the original LFM chirp signal. `spectrogram(fr_y)` produces the plot with the mirrored component since fr_y is the frft of y.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon how else could I plot the time-frequency distribution of the fft?

Comment: So the wiki's clearer - yes you should be seeing TF rotations of the `frft`, and yes you should start with a complex LFM that draws a diagonal from bottom left to top right of the plot.